# Bold in IE11 looks significantly different to bold in chrome - can this be remedied?

Tags: css, windows, google-chrome, internet-explorer, fonts

Some of the titles on https://www.rgraph.net look like this in Google Chrome:

[image]

But in MSIE11 they look like this:

[image]

strong/bold/font-weight appear to have no effect. Is there any way that the font can be made to look "bolder"?

Comment: By the way, seems "comercial" is misspelt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing is not a bug with Internet Explorer 11 strictly speaking (Firefox behaves the same as IE11), but a combination of using Segoe UI Light as a regular weight and a limitation of Segoe UI on Windows 7, which does not come with a proper italic face for the Light weight. Applying `font-weight: bold` to text that's been set in Segoe UI Light this way causes it to be rendered in faux bold, and because an italic face doesn't exist for Segoe UI Light, applying `font-style: italic` causes it to be rendered in faux italics.

Google Chrome appears to compensate for the `font-weight: bold` part by detecting the Segoe UI family and automatically choosing the Bold weight instead of applying faux bold. (This behavior has heritage in WebKit so I'd expect Safari to behave the same with similar font families on macOS.) The proper italics display successfully because a Segoe UI Bold Italic face exists on Windows 7. Interestingly, on Windows 10 (as well as Windows 8/8.1), Google Chrome renders the bold text in Segoe UI Semilight instead, even though its UA stylesheet applies `font-weight: bold`, not `font-weight: bolder`, to `b` elements so I would've expected it to still choose the Bold face, not the Semilight face. I can't explain that one.

In any case, all of this can be corrected by setting your font family to Segoe UI, setting the font weight of your titles to `300` for Light, then setting the font weight of the bold parts to `600` for Semibold or `bold` or `700` for Bold, whichever you prefer. Bold and italics should then work as expected. Just keep in mind that true italics are only supported for Segoe UI Regular and Bold on Windows 7 — italics are supported for just about every available weight of Segoe UI on Windows 8/8.1 and Windows 10, from Light all the way to Black.